Modifying Counting Sort for in place sorting
I'm interested in the following problem from CLRS (Problem 8-2 e)

Suppose that the n records have keys in the range from 1 to k. Show how to modify counting sort so that it sorts the records in place in O(n+k) time. You may use O(k) storage outside the input array. Is your algorithm stable?

I believe I can get an unstable algorithm, as in here. I wonder whether it is possible to satisfy all of

In place sorting
O(n+k) time complexity
O(k) space complexity
Algorithm is stable

My intuition from trying to follow an array manually makes me believe it is impossible, but I would greatly appreciate a proof or an algorithm satisfying all constraints if it exists.

It can be done, but the only algorithm I know is extremely complicated to describe. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.4107
